# multicore CLI commands question

Tags: shell-script, parallelism

I have a collection of 150 CLI commands to execute in a file, on my 12 core machine. Running all 150 tasks in the background bogs the system down and I have found by experience that having 12-18 tasks running is optimal.

In the past, I simply carved up the 150 commands into batch files of 12 or 13 pieces, using the split command, then ran each one.  However some of the batch files finished before others, and I finally end up with 3 or 4 batch files taking a lot longer to finish than others while the other 9 or 8 cores are idle.

My goal is to keep all 12 cores running until all the 150 CLI commands are executed.

Is it possible to have each processor grab one task off the CLI command list of 150, mark that command as executing, and let the other 11 processors grab their own item, until all 150 are done, without the processors tripping over each other and grabbing the same CLI command? The file writes must be unique.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: I think, you might want to see `gnu parallel` pages here: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
cat 150commands.txt | parallel
```

It will run one job per core.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel